# Mimosa karma configuration

Tags: karma-runner, mimosa

Using mimosa I am trying to set the https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor in karma.conf.js using ...

```
files = [
    JASMINE,
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    ...
    {pattern: "source/apps/common/partials/*.html", included: true}
]

preprocessors = {
    "**/*.html": "ng-html2js"
};
```

But I get .. Pre-processor "Ng-html2js" is not registered

I notice in ...

\node_modules\mimosa-karma\node_modules\karma\lib\preprocessors

That there are only 4 preprocessors listed and the one I want is not there.

Does anyone know how I would get mimosa-karma to recognise this pre-processor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a karma person I'm afraid, but it looks like the mimosa-karma-enterprise module, a fork of mimosa-karma, includes that preprocessor?

https://github.com/dretay/mimosa-karma